# How to redirect to an action in Ajax postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Hi I have an Ajax form

```
@Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateItems", "Basket", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Post", OnSuccess = "LoadAjaxSuccess()" }, new { @id = "AjaxForm" })
{

<input type="submit" class="update-basket-button"   value="Update" />

<input type="submit" class="basket-checkout-button"  value="CheckOut" />
}
```

Now when I click Update it should update the db, which works for me but when i click Checkout it should save the changes and redirect to another action. I know in Ajax post back it ignores RedirecToAction(). Whats the best way to achieve this. Thanks in Advance.

The controller action Method is this.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateItems(IList<DocumentAndBasketItemDisplayListDto>basketItems, string button)
    {

        context.UpdateBuyHoldAndQuantityOfBasketItems(basketItems);

        if (string.Equals("CheckOut", button))
        {
            //Response.Redirect("/Order/Index");
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Order");                
        }

        return new EmptyResult();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your `ActionResult` to `JsonResult` and return:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UpdateItems(IListbasketItems, string button)
{
   context.UpdateBuyHoldAndQuantityOfBasketItems(basketItems);
   if (string.Equals("CheckOut", button))
   {
       //Response.Redirect("/Order/Index");
       return Json(Url.Action("Index", "Order"));
   }
   return Json("");
}
```

This way in your ajax method you can retrieve the data and then use something like:

```
function LoadAjaxSuccess(data) {
   document.location.href = data;
}
```

Comment: Hi sergioadh Thanks for the reply, but now I get The "resource cannot be found." error do I need to set "data" in the AjaxOption as well. please advise.

Comment: Check to see that the action name is correct since it cannot find it. It has to be the same in the controller as well as the form.

Comment: I also think the OnSucces should be without "()"

Comment: Thank you Sergioadh, Ya OnSuccess should be without (), that did the trick, Thanks alot agn. Cheers